# How to install armhf package on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, arm, opencv

I'm trying to install Opencv on ODROID XU4 ARM platform where I'm following this tutorial https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/. I am using ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver(32 bits). when I try to add the repository for updates I get the following error [problem with armhf package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJyu8.png), and when I open etc/apt/source.list I get this script 
[source.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCRsd.png)`

Can you please help with this problem ? why do I have problem with downloading armfh package ?

Comment: Is it possible to use 32 bits Ubuntu? There is a mess with your sources.list. You mixed `xenial` and `bionic`

Comment: elaborate please

Comment: This method works on these hardware (ARM base)
  https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/